# Facebook Keyboard shortcut to post (submit) or save a post?

Tags: facebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to find a simple shortcut to submit a post or save a post on Facebook. However, it seems Facebook is ultimately for mouse users.

What I found:

1. https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453
2. http://blog.heyo.com/save-time-with-facebook-shortcuts/

The only "workaround" I came up with: Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> 3 times, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But a shortcut like on the Stack Exchange sites, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> would be a great time saver.

PS: One idea is to use a user script, e.g. https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2711-ffixer (it enables many shortcuts, still the post shortcut is missing).

Comment: Today, 2017-07-03, I have tried `CTRL` + `ENTER` again, and it seems to work now in Facebook. Not in all circumstances, but it is a beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**May 2018:** It's possible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This works in the new form of status posting (which suggests you to also update your story) - I don't remember how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just tested this. <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>⮐ enter</kbd> will **post** a new Status Update. I believe <kbd>⮐ enter</kbd> alone is sufficient when commenting to a post, or when replying to a comment.

Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to immediately **save** a draft of your current Note.

There is no obvious keyboard shortcut for **publishing** a Note. However, that’s understandable, considering Notes are meant to be long-form posts that you’re in no hurry to publish.

When you’re ready to publish, you can avoid using the mouse by pressing <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> 4 times, then <kbd>⮐ enter</kbd>.